# XAML - Why databinding TwoWay don't work on the text property of a combobox in .net 4.0?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, linq-to-xml, binding

Why databinding TwoWay don't work on the text property of a combobox in .net 4.0 (it's working in .net 3.5)?

My code:

I have an xml file like this:

```
<xml>

  <combobox option="" obs="tralala">
    <option value="here" />
    <option value="there" />
  </combobox>

  <combobox option="blue" obs="">
    <option value="one" />
    <option value="two" />
    <option value="three" />
  </combobox>

</xml>
```

and I have a `ListItem` control like that:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <ComboBox MinWidth="75" IsEditable="True"
                  IsReadOnly="False" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                  DataContext="{Binding Path=Element[combobox ]}"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[option], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Attribute[value].Value"
                  Text="{Binding Path=Attribute[option].Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  />
        <TextBox MinWidth="150" AcceptsReturn="False"
                 AcceptsTab="False" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Attribute[obs].Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
      </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
XDocument xdXml;

public MyWindow()
{

    xdXml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\file.xml");

    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = xdXml;

    xdXml.Changed += new EventHandler<XObjectChangeEventArgs>(XdXml_Changed);
}


private void XdXml_Changed(object sender, XObjectChangeEventArgs e)
{
    xdXml.Save(@"C:\fichier.xml");
}
```

I do like that because I can have a `ComboBox` with auto-completion with the different custom option for each, but I can write what I want, and the result is in the attribute option of the element `<combobox>`

It work fine if I target .net 3.5, but only textbox bind if I target .net 4.0

Why?
What can I do?

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. Is it possible you correct your code sample? Please create a new WPF application, copy and paste your sample code into that new project and try to run it. I completed these steps and was not able to get contents into the listbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for doing this code working with framework 4.0 (I've tried to adapt it to your exemple, but i'm not sure. Anyway, this is the idea):

Change your `ListItem` control like that:

```
<ListBox DataContext="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
         IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <!-- Add this collapsed textbox -->
        <TextBox Visibility="Collapsed" DataContext="{Binding Path=Element[combobox]}" Text="{Binding Path=Text, ElementName=cbxComboBox, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged" />
        <!-- Name the Combobox -->
        <ComboBox Name="cbxComboBox" MinWidth="75" IsEditable="True"
                  IsReadOnly="False" DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                  DataContext="{Binding Path=Element[combobox]}"
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="False"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Elements[option], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  DisplayMemberPath="Attribute[value].Value"
                  Text="{Binding Path=Attribute[option].Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  />
        <TextBox MinWidth="150" AcceptsReturn="False"
                 AcceptsTab="False" TextWrapping="NoWrap"
                 Text="{Binding Path=Attribute[obs].Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
      </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

And your new code behind is:

```
XDocument xdXml;

public MyWindow()
{

    xdXml = XDocument.Load(@"C:\file.xml");

    InitializeComponent();

    DataContext = xdXml;

    xdXml.Changed += new EventHandler<XObjectChangeEventArgs>(XdXml_Changed);
}


private void XdXml_Changed(object sender, XObjectChangeEventArgs e)
{
    xdXml.Save(@"C:\fichier.xml");
}

// finally, add this event:
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((XElement)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext).Attribute("option").Value != ((TextBox)sender).Text)
    {
        ((XElement)((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext).Attribute("option").Value = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
    }
}
```

For understand, take a look at:

- [UIElement.TextInput Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.textinput(v=VS.85).aspx)
- [What is the 'right' way to allow arbitrary input in a ComboBox?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/13c6dfad-4062-41b9-85d8-0d5f23dd349b)

Comment: Je vais tester ça à l'ocasion, merci beaucoup ^^

Comment: English please. Most people on SO do not spear French and your answer is not just for the OP; it's for everybody.

Comment: For 2 month, anyone except the two of us seemed interested in this issue and there is a discussion on Area 51 for a French Stack Overflow (http://sl.qyy.fr/frso) where somebody said `"I don't see why they can't ask their questions on StackOverflow. There's no rule that says English Only"`. Anyway, I take care that all important parts of my response be in English, and what Service Informatique said in his comment is: `"I'll test it as soon as I can, thank you very much ^^"`. So, there is nothing important in French, don't worry ^^ (but if you want to check it: http://translate.google.fr/)

Comment: It work perfectly! but what a pity to be forced to do that... Why do they change the perfect behavior of the 3.5 about that? Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 1):

For the moment, the only real solution i found to this problem is to not target Framework 4.0 but Framework 3.5...